# Can't free only one dynamically allocated element

Tags: c, memory, error-handling

So basically I have a function that get's a university structure and fills it with students. It all works! When the university returns to main, all the values are stored within the main university.
Then, when I try to free it (In main),
it bugs out on `braude.students[2].name` for some reason and no one else.
The exception is: CtrlsValidHeapPointer(block).
Why would it free all other dynamically allocated names, but not this one?

```
university getStudentInfo(FILE * file) // Definition of the getStudentInfo function
{ // This function reads student information from a file
  // and updates a university with this information using a pointer
    int i = 1, j;
    char name[99]; // A temporary name to hold the student's name.
    university tempUni; // A temporary university to hold values
    Stud * temp = (Stud*)malloc(sizeof(Stud)); // Allocating memory
                                              //  for an array of students

    if (temp == NULL) // In case there wasn't enough space 
        Error_Msg("Couldn't allocate enough memory.");

    while (getInfo(file, name, &temp[i - 1]) == 8)
    // Using getInfo==8, because in each row, there are 8 variables to scan
    {
        temp[i - 1].name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(name) + 1);
        // Allocating memory for the current element's name.

        if (temp[i - 1].name == NULL) // In case there wasn't enough space, terminate
            Error_Msg("Couldn't allocate enough memory.");
        strcpy(temp[i - 1].name, name);
        // If there was, copy the name from "name" to the current student's name.

        i++; // Increase i by one to have space in memory for one more student
        temp = (Stud*)realloc(temp, i * sizeof(Stud));
        // Realloc temp, to make more space for one more student.

        if (temp == NULL) // In case there wasn't enough space, terminate.
            Error_Msg("Couldn't allocate enough memory.");
    }

    tempUni.students = (Stud*)malloc(sizeof(temp));
    // Allocating memory for students of the university, with the size of temp

    if (tempUni.students == NULL)
        // In case there wasn't enough space, terminate.
        Error_Msg("Couldn't allocate enough memory.");

    tempUni.students->marks[5] = '\0'; // Making the last mark in the string \0
    tempUni.students = temp; // Let the temporary university array of students be temp 
    tempUni.studentCount = i - 1; // How many students
    return tempUni; // Update the pointed university to have the same values as tempUni
}
```

But when I free the dynamically allocated memory in main, like that:

```
free(braude.students[0].name);
    free(braude.students[1].name);
            free(braude.students[2].name); // Crashes here???
            free(braude.students[3].name);
            free(braude.students);
```

Comment: Is that really your code? It's barely readable.

Comment: Stud * temp = (Stud*)malloc(sizeof(Stud)); you said its allocating array of students, but as i see you allocate only 1 Stud

Comment: @YoniNewman it is reallocated for each student.

Comment: Your students must be real `Stud`s.

Comment: I had to do some linebreaking. In case you don't like it please edit it yourself into a shape which you like and which does not require bidirectional scrolling (up/down AND left/right) just for reading. (I have a somewhat largish screen. Yours must be humongous.)

Comment: @xing 
It is, I tried both using pointers with void to update the main function or returning, 
the memory does exist, and when I try to access it from main, it's still there.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks, I'm not used to stackoverflow yet. I tried to do it as organized as I can with the instructions on the right, but couldn't make it lol,

Comment: About your code commenting, things like "// Increase i by one to have space in memory for one more student" are kind of obnoxious and clutter up the code. If it's not clear what `i++;` is doing then you probably have a poorly named variable...

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
tempUni.students = (Stud*)malloc(sizeof(temp));
```

is allocating memory for just one pointer. The code isn't easy to follow, but perhaps it should be

```
tempUni.students = malloc(i * sizeof(Stud));
```

Comment: It allocates an array of students, with the size of temp, which is an array of students..

Comment: wont he gets a memory leak?
in this line he allocated the memory and in  `tempUni.students = temp;` you change it without free

Comment: `Stud * temp` is a pointer, and `sizeof temp` is the size of that pointer – not what it points to.

Comment: @סמיזלדין: `temp` is a pointer to `Stud`. So `sizeof(temp)` is the size of a pointer to `Stud`. So `malloc(sizeof(temp))` only allocates enough space for that pointer, not for an array of students.

Comment: @סמיזלדין why don't you go straight for `tempUni`? What is the `temp` for? And why is either of them a **temp** something?